# Buscar registros con palabras similares SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta que me devuelve palabras que contengan la palabra que paso. El problema que veo al utilizar `LIKE` con el comodín `%`, es que buscará las palabras que empiecen o terminen por dicha cadena.

```
SELECT * FROM buscador where palabra LIKE '%$m%' LIMIT 5
```

Con este ejemplo, si la variable `$m` contiene "mar" me devolverá las palabras que empiecen o acaben por "mar". P. ej. "maravilla".

Lo que necesito es que si paso la variable "maravilla", pueda encontrarme la palabra "mar" también. Necesito ambas cosas y no sé como hacerlo.

Comment: Pero tu mismo ya lo has dicho, **LIKE** busca palabras que contengan tu criterio de búsqueda, si pones "maravilla", supongo que pueda que traiga un resultado como "maravillada" pero no a menos, LIKE trae a mas.  Interesante tu pregunta y estaré atento para ver si alguien tiene alguna sugerencia.

Comment: Ahí está la cosa, buscar una manera de extraer parte de la palabra, indistintamente de la palabra que introduzcas. P. Ej.: "Leyes", que saque "Ley".

Comment: Pero es que el código no puede saber lo que tienes en tu cabeza. LIKE busca a partir de... Osea funciona al revés, como quieres que un lenguaje sepa que al poner **leyenda** lo que quieres es que te traiga **ley**???? Noooo funciona al revés, "ley" te traerá "leyenda, ley, parley" y así... Pero veamos si alguien sugiere algo.

Comment: Así es, entiendo eso perfectamente. Mi duda es para ve si hay alguna sentencia que desconozco, la cual pueda hacer eso. O quizás por medio de PHP :-) Gracias por tus comentarios. Muy interesante.

Comment: Hola, la respuesta se llama **expresiones regulares**, les recomiendo **perderse** un par de horas en estudiarlas, son poderosas!!!.